# Удаление символа из массива циклом for

Tags: c++, строки, циклы, for

Выполняя домашнее задние нашла на просторах интернета такую строчку кода `for (int j = i + 1; str[j - 1] = str[j]; ++j);`. Она удаляет символ и прекрасно вписывается в функцию, которая удаляет символы до пробела:

```
void deleteWords(char str[], int size, char ch1, char ch2) {

    // Инициализирована переменная конца строки
    char endOfStr = '11';
    // Перебор str
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // Если искомый символ найден и это первая буква в слове/начало массива
        if ((str[i] == ch1 or str[i] == ch2) and (str[i - 1] == ' ' or i - 1 <= 0))
            // то удаляем символы до пробела
            while (str[i] != ' ') {
                for (int j = i + 1; str[j - 1] = str[j]; ++j);
                // Если элемент есть конец строки, то выход
                if (str[i] == endOfStr)
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Но, я не совсем понимаю, как именно она работает? Почему на месте, где обычно пишется условие выхода из цикла, в этом примере присваивание? Может кто-нибудь пошагово описать (или подробно объяснить) алгоритм работы этой строчки?

Если конкретнее, то мне интересна именно сточка `for (int i + 1; str[j - 1] = str[j]; ++j)`. Она работает и без цикла while и удаляет один символ. В цикл while я положила его сама, чтобы он искал пробел и выходил из цикла при обнаружении конца строки. Эта строчка полноценна и если ее освободить от while, то она все равно будет работать, только удалять 1 символ, вместо "слова". И вот интересно, как именно это происходит. Каким образом эта команда `str[j - 1] = str[j]` одновременно является условием цикла и инструментом удаления символа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте рассмотрим ваш цикл подробнее

```
for (int j = i + 1; str[j - 1] = str[j]; ++j);
```

Как вообще работает такой цикл?

```
for( инициализация; условие; действие);
```

Примерно - пока верно условие, выполнять действие.

Какое же у нас условие и как оно ***вычисляется***?

```
str[j-1] = str[j]
```

Т.е. в условии выполняется присваивание. Но в С/С++ **результатом присваивания** является присвоенное значение. Не приходилось видеть что-то типа

```
x = y = 5;
```

Т.е. присваиваем 5 переменной `y`, результат, **равный 5**, присваиваем переменной `x`. Так и здесь - после присваивания это все выражение имеет значение, равное только что присвоенному. Примерно как если бы у вас было составное условие:

```
str[j-1] = str[j];
str[j-1]
```

Но условие `str[j-1]` в силу приведения к логическому значению (0 - ложь, не 0 - истина) фактически эквивалентно условию `str[j-1] != 0`.

Таким образом, в цикле выполняется присваивание до тех пор, пока *очередной присвоенный символ не будет нулевым*, т.е. концом строки.

Так понятнее?

Answer (score 1):

Совершенно обычный цикл, просто проверка условия продолжения цикла на истину (не равенство нулю, в случае если на истину проверяется число) происходит после присваивания `str[j - 1] = str[j]`. Цикл работает, пока не встретится конец строки (обозначаемый символом с кодом `0`, насколько я помню `C/C++`). Конец строки тоже скопируется, после чего произойдёт проверка, что же мы там скопировали/присвоили, обнаружится `0`, и цикл закончится.

Comment: Насколько я поняла, Вы говорите о цикле while в целом. Но мне интересна именно сточка `for (int i + 1; str[j - 1] = str[j]; ++j)`. Она работает и без цикла while и удаляет один символ. В цикл while я положила его сама, чтобы он искал пробел и выходил из цикла при обнаружении конца строки. Эта строчка полноценна и если ее освободить от while, то она все равно будет работать, только удалять 1 символ, вместо "слова". И вот интересно, как именно это происходит. Каким образом эта команда `str[j - 1] = str[j]` одновременно является условием цикла и инструментом удаления символа.